# Maximized element inside a container with a sibling

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` element on my page, that looks roughly like that: http://jsfiddle.net/vWBqB/2/.
I want `<select>` element to have maximized width, so it takes all free space in the container with red border.
Setting `width: 100%` makes its width to be equal to the parent container, disregarding floating element on the left. `display: block` has no effect at all.
`Label:` text inside `<label>` may be changed (via JavaScript).
Is there a way to solve this without setting static `width` in pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vWBqB/4/

```
.left {
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right>.select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:20%;

}

.select {

    /* width: 100%; */
    width:80%;
    float:right;
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I need left side to wrap around its content. Have found solution using display: table-cell;, no float, and width:100%; for the right element.